# Invalid value passes validation in wpf datagrid, when "Esc" is pressed

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm, datagrid

I have an Observable collection `SerialList` of a class `SerialItem` containing a single string property `Number`, to which I am binding a DataGrid's ItemsSource. The purpose is for the user to see some preexisting string values, and add some new ones, being validated through a wpf ValidationRule. When the user enters an invalid string and presses "Enter" or tabs out or clicks on another row, the validation fails just fine, presenting the typical Error Template. Pressing "Escape" without further editing, the "wrong" value gets emptied just fine. The problem starts when an existing or already approved cell value is changed to a "wrong" one and the user presses "Enter", validation fails again as expected, but pressing "Escape" immediately after that, the "wrong" value remains, as if having passed validation.

Could anybody perhaps explain or give some pointers to why that happens, or perhaps a solution to that?

The code I used is following:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp8"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="330" Width="200">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <DockPanel>
        <DataGrid DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding SerialList}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowStyle="{StaticResource RowStyle}">
            <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
                <local:SerialValidationRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue"/>
            </DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Serial" Width="*" IsReadOnly="false" Binding="{Binding Path=Number, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}">
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApp8
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public LicenseModel myModel;

        private ObservableCollection<SerialItem> m_SerialList = new ObservableCollection<SerialItem>();

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            myModel = new LicenseModel { 
                Serial_numbers = new Serial_numbers { 
                    SerialNumbers = new ObservableCollection<SerialItem> { new SerialItem { Number = "111111"}, new SerialItem { Number = "222222" } } 
                }
            };

            SerialList = myModel.Serial_numbers.SerialNumbers;

        }


        public ObservableCollection<SerialItem> SerialList
        {
            get
            {
                return m_SerialList; 
            }
            set
            {
                m_SerialList = value;
                myModel.Serial_numbers.SerialNumbers = m_SerialList;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SerialList");
            }
        }

        private void OnSerialListCollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged("SerialList");
        }

    }
}
```

**DataModel.cs**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace WpfApp8
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "serial_numbers")]
    public class Serial_numbers
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "number")]
        public ObservableCollection<SerialItem> SerialNumbers { get; set; }
    }

    public class SerialItem
    {
        public string Number { get; set; }

    }

    public class LicenseModel
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "serial_numbers")]
        public Serial_numbers Serial_numbers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**SerialValidationRule.cs**

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp8
{
    public class SerialValidationRule : ValidationRule
    {
        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            var bindExpressions = value as System.Windows.Data.BindingGroup;

            var bindingitem = bindExpressions.Items[0];

            var serial = bindingitem as SerialItem;

            if (serial.Number == null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(false, "Serial number cannot be empty");
            }

            if (serial.Number.Length != 6)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(false, "Serial number has to be 6 characters long!");
            }

            return new ValidationResult(true, "");

        }
    }
}
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp8.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

    <Application.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="RowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip"

              Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                     Path=(Validation.Errors)/ErrorContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: May very well be related to your base class ViewModelBase. You should post a minimal reproducing project somewhere instead of putting of files here.

Comment: This is the absolut minimum ammount of information of my issue I could provide, in order for people that are willing to help, to just get some code and investigate right away...

Comment: I have tried with a "homemade" ViewModelBase class but also from MVVMLight libraries with no difference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by neutralizing the effect of the "Esc" key, using a command bount to the DataGrid's keypress event.

```
<DataGrid.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Esc" Command="{Binding EscCommand}"/>
</DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

and

```
...
public RelayCommand EscCommand { get; set; }
...
EscCommand = new RelayCommand(OnEscCommand, CanEscCommand);
private bool CanEscCommand()
{
    return true;
}

private void OnEscCommand()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to run the application with the following code and found that when we try to do escape an error value a second time.
We are not updating the source property so the validations are not happing in this case once it's cleared while escaping.

An easy approach to get the error to stay is we can add a new property HasErrors to SerialItem (ViewModel different from DataModel for binding). And instead of performing validations at the time of property update. We can try validating at the DataGrid- RowEditEnding event and update the HasErrors. Where later we can use this HasErrors property to show the styles etc.

Or instead, we can try implementing the INotifyDataErrorInfo on SerialItem. And persist those errors in a dictionary. And make use of these to show errors. Additional details related to the same can be found here:

1. [Link1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/361515/overall-view-validation-with-a-datagrid-and-keeping-to-mvvm)
2. [Link2](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/876349/WPF-Validation-using-INotifyDataErrorInfo)

If you are dealing with multiple properties of the SerialItem to validated. Then it would be better to make use of INotifyDataErrorInfo.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers, but they didn't really help me solve the issue...

Comment: @tombobadil Here are a few more examples hope it might help [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples)